# How to Include one xml file in another xml without root node of source xml file?

Tags: xml, xslt

As asked in the title, I have two XML files like below structure

**A.xml**

```
<Root>
    <J>
        <N>
            //here I want to include B.xml
        </N>
    </J>
</Root>
```

**B.xml**

```
<Root>
    <M></M>
    <O></O>
    <P></P> 
</Root>
```

I am able to use Xinclude but this is including Root element of `B.XML` in `A.xml` also.
I want `A.xml` after including `B.xml` like below

```
<Root>
    <J>
        <N>
            <M></M>
            <O></O>
            <P></P>
        </N>
    </J>
</Root>
```

Please help me out of this.

Answer (score 1):

See here:

https://blogs.gnome.org/shaunm/2011/07/21/understanding-xinclude/

You could do:

```
<include href="someFile.xml" xpointer="xpointer(/Root/M)"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"/>
<include href="someFile.xml" xpointer="xpointer(/Root/O)"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"/>
<include href="someFile.xml" xpointer="xpointer(/Root/P)"   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"/>
```

May well be better approaches - just introducing an idea.

Alternatively, if you have the option you could try a different xml structure.  Could B.xml have "N" as its root note for example?

```
<N>
    <M> 
    <O> 
    <P>
</N>
```

Then include file one level up.  This may well not be possible of course, N could have other content or you may not be able to change xml structure.

Comment: Thanks @afrogonabike for your solution but when I am going to apply this , I am getting the below exception while parsing the A.xml using Java.      Reason: XPointer resolution unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

As afrogonabike mentioned, you could use XInclude along with XPointer to select which elements need to be included. Unfortunately XPointer doesn't specify wildcards, and whether they're possible or not depends on the implementation. So unless you know upfront which elements are gonna be in `B.xml` you're out of luck. There seems to be quite some difference between what from XPoint is supported across implementations, so it could be tricky to get this to work in a somewhat portable or reliable manner.

I suggest you use XSLT instead. XPath is a lot more convenient, and XSLT has a `document()` function to refer to elements in other documents than the one provided as input. Here's a basis for you to work on:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="N">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document('B.xml')/*/*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

By default the stylesheet will copy any nodes and attributes. If it encounters an `N` element, it's going to copy that element, but instead of processing the contents it will apply the templates to the child elements of the root of the referenced document (B.xml).

Note that this only works if `B.xml` is at the same location as your input document. If you're not starting from a file but from, say, a stream, you'd have to come up with something else. It's gonna depend on your environment. Depending on the XSLT processor used, you might be able to supply the contents of B as a parameter to the transformation.

Comment: Thanks @G_H for your solution. Could you please let me know where I can place this logic. As per my understanding I should place in A.xml inside the tag <N> //here </N>. please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @RahulSahu I'm not quite certain what you are asking. Do you mean where to place the stylesheet? XSLT is a separate technology that you can apply on your XML. In a browser you could link a stylesheet to the XML. In Java or C++ or similar you would use an XSLT processor like Xalan. What environment are you working in? Which language?

Comment: I am working in Java and creating the desktop application.

Comment: Then you would use the stylesheet through the Java XML transformation API. Relevant classes can be found in package `javax.xml.transform`. It is part of the Java SE API and has a default implementation, so you don't need additional dependencies. Information on how to use the API and how to use XSLT can be found readily online. The XSLT I supplied should provide a sufficient basis and may actually be all you need, provided you find some way of supplying the document to be included (as a file or parameter).

Comment: Yes, I will found the API in Java, still I am in doubt that where I will put this code, in A.xml? if not then where? I did not found A.xml file location in your code. could you please make me understand. I am very new to xml and xslt.

Comment: The above XSLT would be stored in a separate file (for example one with name `include.xsl`). You use `TransformerFactory.newInstance()` to obtain a `TransformerFactory`. You then use method `newTransformer(Source source)` with that factory. The `Source` is the way you provide the XSLT. I suggest you use a `StreamSource`. The obtained transformer can then transform your `A.xml`, which you also wrap in a `Source`. If `B.xml` is in the same location, make sure to call `setSystemId(File file)` on the A source to make sure it can be resolved during transformation.

Comment: Thanks a lot... @G_H